# angularjs Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just trying to create a plain AngularJS project. I have used AngularJS in previous projects, so I do not see what I am doing wrong.
index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>???</title>
        <base href="OMMITED">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loading-bar.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="limeApp">
        <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loading-bar.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

All files resolve fine. 
app.js

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('limeApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate', 'limeApp.controllers']);

        app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
                $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|skype|chrome-extension):/);
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;

                $routeProvider
                    .when('/', {
                    title: 'Welcome',
                    templateUrl: 'index2.php/',
                    controller: 'defaultController'
                });



            }).run(['$location', '$rootScope', '$window', function ($location, $rootScope, $window) {

            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, current, previous) {
                $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });

            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
                $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
            });

            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, current, previous, error) {
                if (error.status === 404) {
                    $location.path('/404');
                }
            });
        }]);
});
```

The error the console throws at me is:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module limeApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'limeApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Edit: I have tried including the ng-app on the html tag as well.

**SOLUTION:** seems I was missing the closing brackets on the anonymous function. Make sure you close your anonymous function with })();

Comment: Just guessing, but you're referencing the app you're instantiating inside your injectors, here: limeApp.controllers. Does it work if you remove this line?

Comment: Nope. The same error, sadly.

Comment: sometimes get main module error when there is a syntax error inside the module code also

Comment: Strange - seems that if I move app into the index.php file and remove the anonymous function wrapper, everything is fine.

Comment: Update: I was missing the closing brackets on the anonymous function.